# CoreData setting a Relationship loads entire array of Relationships into memory

Tags: ios, core-data

We are reading data from a Bluetooth device and storing it in core data in order to display historical graphs.

The CoreData Model has two entities. A `Battery` and a `Reading`.
Each battery has a one to many relationship with a reading.

```
Battery <-->> Reading
```

The problem is, after a while of usage, the database gets fairly large. When setting a `Reading` to `Battery` relationship, the `Battery`, and all previous `Reading`s, are loaded into memory causing performance issues.

Is there a way to insert a relationship without firing the fault and loading all the `Reading`s on a `Battery`?

This is essentially how we create a `Reading` and tie it to a `Battery`...

```
// Finding a Battery
func find(serialNumber: String, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> Battery? {
        let request = NSFetchRequest< Battery >(entityName: "Battery")
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "serialNumber == %@", serialNumber)
        request.predicate = predicate
        do {
            let battery = try context.fetch(request)
            return battery
        } catch {
            print(error)
            return nil
        }
    }
```

Creating and assigning a `Reading`

```
let context: NSManagedObjectContext!

let battery = Battery.find(serialNumber: "1234", in: context)

let entityDescription = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Reading", in: context)
var reading = Reading(entity: entityDescription!, insertInto: context)
reading.battery = battery

try? context.save()
```

If I inspect the `battery` it initially faults and contains no `Reading`s. Once I assign `reading.battery = battery`, the battery loads every single previous reading into memory.  This can be quite a lot after collecting data for a while.

We show a "live" graph of `Reading` data, so it's important we save the data fairly often.

Is there a way to make this more performant and not load all previous readings into memory?  Ideally, I'd like to let the user go back in time to see usage data (up to a certain point).  Currently saving data ends up bogging down the system.

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Don't use a relationship? Add an attribute like battery serial number to Reading and then use that in a predicate when you want to fetch readings for a battery

Comment: I was considering that, but I'd have to do a hefty migration I'd imagine (Or just delete all their data).